# Выбор диапазона для поиска максимального значения в зависимости от значения ячейки

Tags: excel

Ввожу

```
=ЕСЛИ(ГОД=1999;МАКС(B5:B16);"Нет данных";ЕСЛИ(ГОД=2001;МАКС(D5:D16);"Данных нет"))
```

Excel выводит:

> Вы ввели для этой функции аргументов: Слишком много

Что можно сделать с этим?

Comment: А что вы сделать то пытались вообще? Из кода функции совершенно теряется суть вашего условного оператора.

Comment: Я в одну ячейку ввожу год, если введу 1999, то засунуть в ячейку максимум с диапазона B5:B16, если введу 2000, то засунуть в ячейку максимум диапазона C5:C16

Comment: А, тогда кусок с `;"Нет данных"` лишний

Comment: Типа такого? =ЕСЛИ(A1=1999;МАКС(B1:B7); (ЕСЛИ(A1=2001;МАКС(C1:C7);Нет данных)))

Comment: Только не совсем понятно, как должна исполниться секция с "Нет данных", так как Excel по умолчанию считает пустую ячейку за 0 вроде.

Comment: В лабе написано скопировать оттуда формулу, а она там именно с этой штукой "Нет данных"

Comment: Спасибо, без "Нет данных" всё работает)

Comment: Только без первой "фразы, вторая нормально , хотя текст там, где должно быть число, не всегда хорошо.  Вариант: `=МАКС(ЕСЛИ(там=1999;диапазон1;ЕСЛИ(там = 2001;диапазон2;0))` Учитесь формулировать задачу (заголовок уже изменен)